# The projection of n-joint distribution onto 2-joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, optimal-transport, marginal-distribution

Let $P$ be a probability distribution on the product of Polish spaces $X_1\times \cdots \times X_N$. In particular, $X_N=X_j$. Suppose the marginal distribution of $P$ on $(X_i)$ are $(\mu_i)$, where $(\mu_i)$ are absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. In particular, $\mu_N=\mu_j$.

My question is if the projection of $P$ onto 2-dimension space is the same regardless of $j$ or $N$. That is, if for any $i\neq j$ and $i\neq N$, we have:
$$P(X_1\times\cdots\times A_i\times\cdots\times A_j\times \cdots\times X_N)=P(X_1\times \cdots\times A_i\times \cdots\times X_{N-1}\times A_j)$$
for all Borel sets $A_i\subset X_i$ and $A_j\subset X_j$.

This question might be related with if one can uniquely determine the 2-joint distribution from two marginals.

- [Build joint distribution of A and B](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375838/can-the-marginal-distributions-of-a-c-and-b-c-be-used-to-build-joint-distributio);
- [Equal marginals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500730/if-marginal-probabilities-equal-can-we-say-anything-about-joint-distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $j=2$ an $N=3$. Suppose all the $X_i$ are $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure
and let $P$ by the distribution of $U,U,V$ where $U,V$ are independent uniform variables in $[0,1]$. In other words, $P$ is the image of Lebesgue measure on the square $[0,1]^2$ under the map $(x,y) \mapsto (x,x,y)$.
You get a negative answer to your question by taking $A_1$ and $A_2$ to be disjoint intervals.

Comment: Thank you Prof. Peres so much! Your response is very helpful. Following the idea in your example, for a map $T(x,y)=(x,y,x)$, and $P$ is a probability measure on $X\times Y$ with marginal $U,V$ (not necessarily a uniform distribution). First collection of measures $Q\in\mathbb{P}(X\times Y\times X)$ satisfying the marginals are $U,V,U$; and $(\mathrm{proj}_1,\mathrm{proj}_3)_{\#}Q=(id,id)_{\#}U$; second collection of measures $Q\in\mathbb{P}(X\times Y\times X), Q=T_{\#}P$. Are these two collections are the same?